# Conservar el dato en moneda en un input con keypress Jquery

Tags: jquery

Buen día comunidad.

Tengo un Template de Thymeleaf y en un input recibe un dato entero que viene de un servicio en spring, el dato llega como un entero y con jquery ya se parsea a un formato en moneda, llega así(ejemplo): `200000`, y ese valor con jquery se vuelve así en el input -> `200,000.00`.

Hasta ahí todo bien pero si yo quiero editar ese input quiero que ese parseo se conserve, si tengo el valor de  -> 200,000.00 y yo lo edito se pierde el formato(se quita, las comas y el punto).

Investigando encontré que con la función de `keypress` de *JQuery* puedo solucionar esto solo que en esa parte no he podido hacer que si por ejemplo tengo `200,000.00` y yo edito ese input a no se unos `50,000.00` los edite sin tener que poner la coma ni el punto .
Mi código:

```js
$(function(){
       console.log("Document.ready: Documento listo");
       $().ready(function() {
                        
          num=$("[data-field='montoMeta']").val();
          console.log("Valor Antes del Cambio");
          console.log(num);
                        
          var numero = parseInt(num);
     
          var formatoNumero = function(numero) {
              var cadena = numero.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              return cadena.indexOf("-") != -1 ? "-$" + cadena.replace("-", "") : cadena;
          };
                        
          var numeroSalida = formatoNumero(numero);
                        
          console.log("Valor Despues del Cambio");
          console.log(numeroSalida);
     
          var valorRecuperado = numeroSalida.toString();
          console.log("Valor Regresado a String..");
          console.log(valorRecuperado);
    
           $("[data-field='montoMeta']").val(valorRecuperado);
                        
           console.log(" = Cambio!! . Key...... ");
                        
           // -- keypress JQuery
            $().keypress(function(){
                console.log("Metodo KeyPress")
                var obtenerKey=$("[data-field='montoMeta']").val();
                console.log(obtenerKey);
                            
                var formatoNumero = function(numero) {
                  var cadena = numero.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                  return cadena.indexOf("-") != -1 ? "-$" + cadena.replace("-", "") : cadena;
                };
                            
            });         
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="montoMeta"><small>Valor de tu meta</small></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control p17-input" data-field="montoMeta" value="$25,000,000.00 MXN" th:value="${fondo.tuNumero}">
</div>
```

Anexo de como se parsea el dato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y si lo edito se pierde el formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que capturas en tu `[data-field='montoMeta']` es la característica de tu input el cual vas a formatear.

Bueno, yo haría esto, suponiendo que mi id sería monto:

```js
$("#monto").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="monto">
```

Como verás, continúa el formato que solicitas a pesar que ya formateas el número cuando lo obtienes.

Por otra parte, también te recomendaría usar [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat), ya es soportado por muchos navegadores y puedes simplemente escoger el país y definir la salida con el formato que tendrá, ya que solo necesitas el punto décimal para trabajar.

```js
let monto = document.getElementById('monto');

monto.addEventListener('input', () => {
  $('#salida').html(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(monto.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="monto" value="10000">

<div id="salida"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, me base en ellas para poder aplicar el cambio y ya pude realizarlo, Se los agradezco mucho.

Comment: No te preocupes. Estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: Tu lo has dicho y gracias nuevamente