# Formato Moneda en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Al manejar el formato de moneda con JavaScript, no logro obtener el resultado que quiero

**Ejemplo**

`10000` debería ser `$10.000`

```
function getvalue() {
    var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
    var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;

    var result = (meses * valor)/ 12;
    document.getElementById("total").value = result;
    result.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD"
    });
}
```

Comment: Sale algun error? O cual es el resultado de tu funcion?

Comment: Mira esta respuesta a ver si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/438037/184555

Comment: Ademas, primero estas seteando el valor y despues dandole el formato

Answer (score 0):

El detalle esta en que primero agregas el valor y luego le das formato.

Asumiendo que tu elemento con `id="total"` es un `input`, podrías usar:

```js
function getvalue() {
    var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
    var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;

    var result = (meses * valor) / 12;
    document.getElementById("total").value = result.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD"
    });
}

getvalue()
```

```html
<input id="meses" value="2" oninput="getvalue()">
<input id="valor" value="10" oninput="getvalue()">

<br>
<br>

<input id="total">
```

Si tu elemento con `id="total"` no es un `input`, solo cambia:

```
document.getElementById("total").value
```

Por:

```
document.getElementById("total").innerText
```

Comment: El resultado se genera dinámicamente sin necesidad de un botón, como podría adaptar el ejemplo pues probé este y me sigue saliendo el número entero

Comment: En ese caso se tiene que responder con el evento `oninput`, la experiencia de usuario es mejor pero debes de ser cuidadoso ya que algunas cosas pueden ser costosas de calcular y por ende tardarse mucho, **pero** para este caso hacer una multiplicación y dar un formato no tiene mayor problema. :)

Ya ha sido editada la respuesta para que puedas jugar con ello.